# How do I get id_token to properly load in Cloud Run?

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, google-cloud-run

I have a Django app that I have been working on.  When I run it locally it runs perfectly.  When I run it in a container using Cloud Run I get the following error:

'Credentials' object has no attribute 'id_token'

Here is the offending code (payload is a dictionary object):

```
def ProcessPayload(payload):
  # Get authorized session credentials
  credentials, _ = google.auth.default()
  session        = AuthorizedSession(credentials)
  credentials.refresh(Request(session))
  # Process post request
  headers        = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {credentials.id_token}'}
  response       = requests.post(URL, json=payload, headers=headers)
```

In my local environment, the refresh properly loads credentials with the correct id_toled for the needed header, but for some reason when the code is deployed to Cloud Run this does not work.  I have the Cloud run instance set to use a service account so it should be able to get credentials from it.  How do I make this work? I have googled until my fingers hurt and have found no viable solutions.

Answer (score 2):

So, after much playing around I found a solution that works in both places.  Many thanks to Paul Bonser for coming up with this simple method!

```
import google.auth
from   google.auth.transport.requests import AuthorizedSession, Request
from   google.oauth2.id_token import fetch_id_token
import requests

def GetIdToken(audience):
  credentials, _ = google.auth.default()
  session = AuthorizedSession(credentials)
  request = Request(session)
  credentials.refresh(request)
  if hasattr(credentials, "id_token"):
    return credentials.id_token
  return fetch_id_token(request, audience)

def ProcessPayload(url, payload):
  # Get the ID Token
  id_token = GetIdToken(url)
  # Process post request
  headers        = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {id_token}'}
  response       = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 1):

When executing code under a Compute Service (Compute Engine, Cloud Run, Cloud Functions), call the metadata service to obtain an OIDC Identity Token.

```
import requests

METADATA_HEADERS = {'Metadata-Flavor': 'Google'}
METADATA_URL = 'http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/' \
                           'instance/service-accounts/default/identity?' \
                           'audience={}'

def fetch_identity_token(audience):
    # Construct a URL with the audience and format.
    url = METADATA_URL.format(audience)

    # Request a token from the metadata server.
    r = requests.get(url, headers=METADATA_HEADERS)

    r.raise_for_status()
    return r.text

def ProcessPayload(payload):
  id_token = fetch_identity_token('replace_with_service_url')
  # Process post request
  headers        = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {id_token}'}
  response       = requests.post(URL, json=payload, headers=headers)
```

The equivalent **curl** command to fetch an Identity Token looks like this. You can test from a Compute Engine instance:

```
curl -H "metadata-flavor: Google" \
  http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/identity?audience=URL
```

where URL is the URL of the service you are calling.

[Authentication service-to-service](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service)

I have seen this metadata URL shortcut (for Cloud Run), but I have not verified it:

```
http://metadata/instance/service-accounts/default/identity?audience=URL
```

Comment: So, is there a good way for the code to detect whether it is running locally or in the cloud in order to know which method to use (as I don't think this method will work locally)?

Comment: Oh, and BTW ... thanks!

Comment: One last thing ... I'm a little confused as to what 'replace_with_service_url' means.  Isn't this the same as the URL that I am trying to access in the post call?

Comment: @Cyberclops Yes, the **audience** URL is usually the URL of the service that you are calling. However, it depends on what the service expects when it validates the audience value. Your question does not include details on the service that you are calling. The documentation will specify authorization details. The key item is that you now know how to create an OIDC Identity Token from Cloud Run. You can then play with the audience value based upon documentation.